# SystemVerilog support of icarus (iverilog compiler)

Tags: verilog, hardware, system-verilog, iverilog, icarus

I am using `iverilog` on a Mac, and I have problem compiling some codes that include `always_ff` and `always_comb` blocks. ModelSim compiles those codes without any problem. Is it possible to configure `iverilog` so as to support `always_ff` and `always_comb` blocks, or they are just not supported by the compiler?

Comment: Is there any other way I can compile SystemVerilog on a Mac ? Or I have to stuck with VM (or native windows ? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`always_comb`, `always_latch` and `always_ff` are some of the keywords that were introduced in the SystemVerilog [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).   They are not part of the Verilog IEEE Std 1364-2005, which is what the Icarus Verilog compiler supports.

I am not aware of any free SystemVerilog simulators.  However, you can always simulate and synthesize your SystemVerilog design using [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/).

Comment: The free SystemVerilog simulators are only supported on the Windows platform, and those do not support the full language.

Comment: @dave_59: I believe Altera Modelsim Starter Edition is supported on both Windows as well as Linux.  Not sure about MacOS though.

Comment: Verilator is an open source simulator that supports a synthesizable subset of SystemVerilog: https://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilator

Answer (score 11):

AndresM's answer is not completely accurate. Icarus verilog defaults to IEEE Std 1364-2005, and it is the better supported standard, but that can be changed with the `-g` switch. From `man iverilog`:

> -g1995|-g2001|-g2001-noconfig|-g2005|-g2005-sv|-g2009|-g2012
>
> Select the Verilog language generation to support in the compiler.  This selects between IEEE1364-1995, IEEE1364-2001, IEEE1364-2005, IEEE1800-2005, IEEE1800-2009,  or  IEEE1800-2012.   Icarus Verilog  currently  defaults  to the IEEE1364-2005 generation of the language. This flag is used to restrict the language to a set of keywords/features, this allows simulation of older Verilog code that may use newer keywords and for compatibility with other tools. Much of the IEEE1800 generations functionality is not currently supported.  The IEEE1800 generations do parse all  the keywords, so they can be used to verify that IEEE1364 compliant Verilog code does not use any of the new IEEE1800 keywords.

Indeed, it tells you so when trying to use unpacked arrays in ports:

> error: Ports cannot be unpacked arrays. Try enabling SystemVerilog support.